# How to completely remove jupyterlab and reinstall a fresh one in ubuntu using pip?

Tags: ubuntu, pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I installed jupyter on ubuntu and something messed up. I tried different methods (some with sudo) and nothing works fine.
Tried to delete every files and folder named `jupyter` from `../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/...` , `/usr/local/` `/usr/lib/` and so on. But every time I want to install again using `pip3 install jupyterlab` this error shows up:

`Requirement already satisfied: Successfully installed jupyter-client-6.1.7 jupyter-core-4.6.3 jupyterlab-2.2.8 jupyterlab-pygments-0.1.1 jupyterlab-server-1.2.0`

when I try to run using `jupyter notebook` it says:

`Exception: Jupyter command jupyter-notebook not found.`

I tried `pip3 uninstall jupyter` and other ways to uninstall and install but non is working.